# Image of a 16Gb card containing unpartitioned space at the end: Truncating possible?

Tags: sd-card, image, partition

I wanted to prepare a distro for some friends.
As I didn't have anything else lying around, I used a 16Gb SD card.

I started with the default Debian Weezy 2Gb image and did not do any resizing.
Now, as I am done, I wanted to create an image of what I did, but I get a 16Gb file, containing 14Gb of *unpartitioned (not partitioned and free)*  space at the end.

[I used Windows // Win32DiskImager as I have nothing free to stick into the rPI right now]

> Can I just truncate the image file right behind the partitioned space and transfer the leading part onto a smaller card, then?

Comment: If you have access to a linux computer, run `dd if=/dev/path/to/SD/card of=~/SpecialImage.img`, then install GParted and run `gparted ~/SpecialImage.img`. Once GParted opens up your `.img` file, simply resize the partitions to your liking! (Both commands must be run as root, `sudo su` should get you what you need. When the `$` switches to a `#`, you're Root. Be careful, this is the Linux equivalent of God.) GParted is basically a GUI frontend for the arcane partiton management tools you'll need. Using GParted just makes everything so much simpler and likelier to succeed.

Comment: Plese read my question carefully.

Comment: Yes, I read your question, and I can tell you that just truncating a disk image is dangerous. Sure, you can just clip off the last bytes of an image, but there's no gaurantee that you won't accidentally shear off any files, especially since [Linux intentionally spaces its files out](http://www.howtogeek.com/115229/htg-explains-why-linux-doesnt-need-defragmenting/). Plus, there might be some important metadata at the end of the filesystem or something like that. It's a safer bet overall to use the proper filesystem resizing utilities than to try to just lop off the end of a file yourself.

Comment: Well, but I am talking about unpartitioned space. Even Linux won't put any data on Disk Space that is marked unpartitioned but stay within the block as written in the Partition Table. 
My concern was caused by the image file format: It may be, that the image file has metadata lying at the end of the file, so I was worried cutting off file information. (Hope my previous comment didn't sound too hard, sry ;)

Comment: Ohh, I get what you're saying now. If you're worried about any corrupted trailing free space, then run GParted on the image after you've truncated it. It'll probably list the last area as either "unallocated" or "corrupted" - create a new "unformatted" partition in that space. Then, you won't have any issues. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finally found a resource that is explaining my question.

> http://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux

**Short:**

Yes, truncating is possible!

***Summary of the process:***

Extracting the partition information from the image using `fdisk`:

```
$ fdisk -lu image.img
Disk image.img: 4096 MB, 4096000000 bytes, 8000000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a1bc7

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
image.img1              2048     5872026     5869978    b  W95 FAT32
```

We see, that the partition has a size of about 2,8Gb (5872026 * 512), the rest is *unpartitioned*.

So, everything after the end of the partition can be removed.
This will be done with the tool `truncate`. Don't forget to add 1 to the number of sectors, as block-numbers start at 0.

```
$ truncate --size=$[(5872026+1)*512] image.img
```

---

**Edit:**

For those being too lazy to switch to Linux:
Also works on Windows with ***Cygwin***'s `fdisk.exe` and `truncate.exe`!

***What is Cygwin?***

I may cite: "Cygwin: Get that Linux feeling - on Windows" (https://www.cygwin.com/).
It is a set of executeables that can run under Windows, but provide all the command line programs you usually know from Linux.
Cygwin can take very long to install if you select every package during install, but to follow this example, simply make sure, that besides the default configuration, also the packages `util-linux` (fdisk) and `coreutils` (truncate) are selected.
Depending on your environment, you man need to add `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: What package do I need to install to get `fdisk.exe` and `truncate.exe`?

Comment: Hi @PythonNut, I updated my answer above and added the required packages :o)

Comment: What if the partition has the size of the disk, even if less is used?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I would like to show how to do this process on Mac, because it is not as easy: `fdisk` doesn't have the `-l` option, and `truncate` is not installed by default:

### 1. Step 1: Install *truncate* on Mac OS X:

You need MacPorts or Homebrew for this. I use MacPorts. If you don't have one of these, go ahead and install them first. [Link to MacPorts](https://www.macports.org)

Now, we can install *truncate*. Open up your Terminal and type:

```
sudo port install truncate
```

For Brew installation:

```
brew install truncate
```

This should do it.

### 2. Use Disk Utilities to mount our IMG so that it is visible to the *diskutil* terminal command.

You will see in a moment why we need this step. Open the Disk Utility app. Click on **File** *(on the top bar)* **-> Open Disk Image** and select your IMG file.

### 3. Check the partition size of the IMG and where it is mounted.

On a Terminal, type:

```
diskutil list
```

And it should show something like this, somewhere in the end:

```
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +16.0 GB    disk3
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    62.9 MB    disk3s1
   2:                      Linux                         3.9 GB     disk3s2
```

So, we see that about 12GB are unpartitioned. We need to truncate those.

The reason we need this command is to check out where the disk image is mounted. In my case, it is under: **/dev/disk3**

### 4. Find out the actual partition size.

3.9 GB and 62.9 MB are values that won't work with truncate. We need to find the partition sizes in bytes.

### 5. Run *fdisk*.

In your Terminal, run this command:

```
   fdisk /dev/diskX
```

Where **X** is the number that you found out in the previous step. This should result in something like this:

```
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C    0 130   3 -    8  40  32 [      8192 -     122880] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 83    8  40  33 -  478  79  49 [    131072 -    7553024] Linux files*
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

### 6. Time to *truncate*!

On your terminal, `cd` to the directory that your image is. Then, write:

```
truncate FILE SIZE
```

FILE is your file of course.

SIZE is the size in bytes. What I did, is to add to the **size** column of the `fdisk` command, the **start** column and multiply by 512. So, in my case SIZE will be: **512 * (7553024 + 131072) = 3934257152**, which is approximately 3.9 GB.

You will need the *start* and *size* of the **last partition** that is shown by `fdisk`. (Not necessarily the biggest, but the one in the end of the IMG file)

> I experimented a bit, and whenever I entered 7553024 * 512 or (7553024
>   + 1) * 512 bytes, the IMG file was corrupt. So, just to be sure, do it as I indicate above. It might add more than actually needed, but it is a safe option.

### 7. (Optional) Easily test if the IMG is not corrupt.

Go once more in the Disk Utility, and try to open the new IMG file as before. If it mounts, you can also see the new *(smaller)* size. If it doesn't mount, something went wrong. 
(Maybe try to increase the size in the `truncate` command)

> This is not the best test, but it is a sure way to check if the new
>   IMG is corrupt or not. So, don't really count on it, but it is worth
>   the try...

**I hope someone finds this helpful!**

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for expanding knowledge :)
Good that you pointed out that `512*(Size+1)` does not work. As you can see, I used `End` and not `Size`, as you have to keep both partitions if there are more than one. So, using `7553024 + 131072` (`+1`) is 100% correct!

Answer (score 1):

Recent Win32DiskImager actually has an option to only include allocated partitions in the disk image. This will do the trimming in one click.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, makes it much easier on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Just something I have recently noticed as I do a lot of this Win32diskimg operations for backing up my RPI images for deployment.  I recently starting testing SD "trimming" fstrim to clean parts of the SD card not in use for theoretical wear leveling.  Not sure about the effect it will have but one side effect was when I imaged the 16GB SD partition and then used 7zip to compress it.  I went from the usual 16GB to 9.5GB to now a 2.5GB file.  I am testing now to make sure nothing is wrong but it appears that using TRIM to mark the unused space as 0's makes the image compression far more efficient (which does make sense).  Just wanted to report at this was super easy to accomplish and no multiple steps.

Comment: While not wrong it doesn't really address the question.